# Use state updater "not a function" when passed by prop to component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So, basically my use state updater is giving an error "Uncaught TypeError: setStep is not a function".

**Parent component**

```
const [step, setStep] = useState(0)  
<StepZero step={step} setStep={setStep}/>
```

**Child Component**

```
const StepZero = (step:number, setStep:any) => {

const handleIncrement = () => {
    setStep(step+1)
}
return
...
<div onClick={handleIncrement}>SELECT & CONTINUE</div>
```

State is working fine in parent component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
const StepZero = ({ step, setStep }: {
    step: number;
    setStep: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>;
}) => {
```

See [Functional components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components).
You have to destructure the props first. Note that you have to import the types `Dispatch` and `SetStateAction` from React.